# How to beat 2 singles players playing doubles

Tags: tennis, tactics

What kind of strategy should you use if you are 2 doubles players playing against 2 singles players? Would lobs be a good option?

Comment: Your question seems to be making some assumptions that you haven't included in your question. Why do you think using a different or specific strategy against primarily singles players in a doubles match is something you need to do? In professional tennis, the top doubles teams are able to beat a team made up of singles players by using the same effective doubles strategies they use in all of their matches. The doubles players might choose to attack known weaknesses of the singles players team, but that isn't really different from any other doubles match strategy.

Comment: As federer said...play the ball and not the guy.

Comment: One would think that a starting point might be playing to the center of the court, trying to take advantage of any strategy errors or communication issues.  But I am hopeful that a more knowledgeable and detailed answer will come that this idea stub.

Comment: Only leaving a comment since it is opinion.... For me singles these days are typically played baseline to baseline... but in doubles it is typical to have one player at the net. I have found (myself included) that singles players are not as good at the net especially if they are standing there rather than approaching. Either target the net player or wide enough for them to think twice to go for the ball. they are also less likely to cross infront of the net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion lobs would not be a good option, since they do not capitalize on the typical strengths of doubles players.

Assuming none of the players have glaring weaknesses and the differences are just in singles/doubles specialty, standard doubles play should be the strategy. That is, the usual mixture of poaching and varied formations. The effectiveness will come from the skill and experience in playing doubles as opposed to a specific type of shot.